# Why sub-organizational unit in Google Workspace is not displayed in my GCP account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, architecture, google-workspace

I have one domain registered in Google Domain and I am able to configure Google workspace for this domain as an organization. This organization has automatically propagated to my GCP account as well and I have created folder structure and projects in this organization.
[image: My Organization structure in Google Workspace]

Now I have created a sub-organization as shown in the picture in google Workspace. I was expecting the new sub-organization to be automatically get reflected in my GCP account. However, it didn't happen as expected.

Kindly suggest a resolution.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "This organization has automatically propagated to my GCP account as well". That is not how Google Cloud and Google Workspace interoperate. A Workspace organization is not the same as a Google Cloud organization and they are not linked as far as structure and operations are concerned. Also, Google Cloud does not have sub-organizations. The equivalent could be considered "Folders". Workspace and GCP are two different products. AFAIK one does not affect the other except for identities.

Answer (score 0):

- This is described in the article [Managing multiple organizations](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/managing-multiple-orgs), in the mentioned article states :

```
The Organization node establishes ownership of the projects and folders underneath it in the Google Cloud Platform resource hierarchy. Your Google Workspace or Cloud Identity account is associated with exactly one Organization node. Each Google Workspace or Cloud Identity account is also associated with a single domain, such as example.com.
```

- It is described that your workspace organization is associated with only one Organization Node, please note that a Workspace Domain is not the same as an organization node,  nor the domains and organization are linked.